# Is it possible to fetch the data of only one attribute of an Entity in Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

I have an entity in Core Data with multiple attributes. In order to increase the performance of the app, I would like to fetch only one attribute of that entity. Is that possible to do and if so, then how? Or should I just use predicates to fetch the entities that I need and from them access the values of their attributes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a few things; how many entities are you fetching, do you ever want anything else, what is your real performance problem?

First of all use Instruments to make sure that your problem is actually where you think it is. Core data uses faulting and batching to make it very memory and performance efficient. An entity's attribute data is not brought into memory until it is accessed.

If you really want to only fetch a single attribute from your entities then you can make a fetch request with the `propertiesToFetch` value set to the attributes you care about. If you do this with a managed object `resultType`, then AFAIK I know this will use *more* memory, as it will make all the result objects be a partial fault (with those properties populated) rather than full faults.

If you use the dictionary `resultType`, then you'll get back no managed objects at all, just an array of dictionaries with the relevant attribute populated.

Comment: Agreed, fetching more than one property is almost never the cause of performance problems.

Comment: I just want to fetch one attribute of an entity for measuring the performance in XCTest for a particular method. That entity has 7 other attributes. I just wanted to know, whether it is possible, and if so, how faster that would be.

Comment: Your test will tell you, but it sounds like you’re doing premature optimisation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the single property. Here is the [Apple's way](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html)

Comment: What's the swift syntax look like for this? I've got an entity with a date attribute...that's all I want is the date.